# matplotlib - plot two data sets with labels in the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot two data point categories in the same `matplotlib` plot using two different colours.

Following code plot one category of data points with labels.

```
import matplotlib
import pylab as plt

x = [-0.39615277,-0.31426806,-0.17823952,-0.43836375,-0.26388058,-0.52400482, -0.26388058, -0.32637322]
y = [0.28005737,0.44953214, 0.26899154, 0.36850831, -0.34592143, -0.24640466, -0.34592143, -0.45966878]
n=['romeo','juliet','happy','dagger','live','die','free','hampshier']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

But I have following data set which has to be plotted in the same figure with a different colour.

```
x1 = [-0.31086574,-0.40733041,-0.59446137,-0.60304575,-0.1428143]
y1 = [0.36293322,0.54074246, 0.20005441, -0.6953914, -0.22866156]
n1=['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5']
```

How to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note: this post has been edited to remove my first unhelpful answer and replace it with a proper one. New here, sorry. :)

Plotting two scatter plots will plot them on the same figure. So where you have `ax.scatter(x,y)`, put the second scatter plot `ax.scatter(x1,y1,c='red')` directly afterwards and it will be on the same figure. Later you can annotate the second set of points with

`for i, txt in enumerate(n1): 
   ax.annotate(txt, (x1[i],y1[i]))`

Comment: Please add some description about your answer. It maybe short but useful to understand your answer.

Comment: @TheBigH: Hey TheBigH! I need to know how to plot these two data sets in the same figure? That is my main question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking how to plot the points in different colors. Plotting two scatter lots will plot them on the same figure. So where you have `ax.scatter(x,y)`, put the second scatter plot `ax.scatter(x1,y1,c='red')` directly afterwards and it will be on the same figure. Later you can annotate the second set of points with `for i, txt in enumerate(n1):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x1[i],y1[i]))`

Comment: @TheBigH :  Thanks that worked. Please put your answer as an answer not as a comment. So I can accept it, also you get points. :)

Comment: Done. Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow and still figuring out how things work here.